# Bluetooth connection to Sony Bluetooth Headphones (Macbook Pro 2014 / iPhone 6s)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I've purchased set of Sony Headphones (WH1000XM2).

They are great, but I can't figure out how to have two simultaneous connections with my MacBook and iPhone.  The headphones will connect to either individually but not at the same time.  I want to have it that I can listen to music on the Mac, and answer a call on the phone when it comes in.  I have tried this with a PC and iPhone and it's fine.

I believe I need to create a A2DP connection on the Mac, and a HFP connection on the iPhone. That's based on the info here - http://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/wh1000xm2/v1/en/contents/TP0001513163.html
 
I've downloaded Apple's Bluetooth Explorer and tried various settings related to "Disable Hands-free profile" and "aptX" but nothing works. I’m at the stage where I’m testing random permutations as I don’t understand the options.

Does anyone know if this can be done?  Headphones will be going back if not.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way Bluetooth works.  While you can connect multiple devices (multiple BT profiles) you can't connect them simultaneously.

> I want to have it that I can listen to music on the Mac, and answer a
>   call on the phone when it comes in.

This is where [Apple's Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) comes into play.  You can have your BT headphones connected to your Mac and simultaneously make/receive phone calls and have them come through the headphones (or via the internal mic and speaker if you want).

Comment: Hi Allan. Thanks for the comment. I have this working with my smart tv and iPhone. I’m listening to the tv via the headphones. My iPhone rings. The tv pauses automatically and I get the phone’s ringtone through the headphones. I’m trying to achieve the same; but swap smart tv for Mac. ‘Simultaneously’ might be the wrong word. I’m not looking for both to play sound at the same time. Thanks

Comment: I don't know that can be done on a Mac.  I know it can't be done with my Bose QC 35's.  But using continuity made it moot.

Comment: Thanks again. My issue is that I walk away from my desk when I get calls. So I would rather answer it on my iPhone / headphones than Mac / headphones. Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I'm working on it. it was about 2 month. But I have not been successful.  At the same time, 2 iphone or android are connected. But it's not a MacBook. This is due to the MacBook. What we need to find is that the Mac computer only makes the A2DP bluetooth connection. But I have tried hard, but I have not succeeded.

I could not find any solution. I found a workaround for making phone calls and listening to music at the same time.

1- I connected my headset to a computer with a microphone AUX cable.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/BASEUS-Brand-1-2M-AUX-Audio-Cable-With-MIC-3-5mm-male-to-male-extension-AUX/32696482589.html

2- I installed the Hands Free 2 program and connected it via Bluetooth.

https://www.tunabellysoftware.com/handsfree2/

Now I can answer calls from my computer while listening to music.

it's a temporary solution but it's working for now. I recommend.

Comment: i try disable HFP on mac, but nothing,

Comment: I know this won't be helpful, but I returned the Sony headphones and bought Bose Comfort 3.  It is so much easier and they work with the mac and iPhone as they should.